# SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 554 5.7.1 : Client host rejected: Access denied

Tags: email, smtp

I am trying to send mail through phpmailer with smtp.i am using the host which i am using on my outlook with same username and password.I am getting an error .can anyone help me how to fix this.

My Error:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 554 5.7.1 : Client host rejected: Access denied
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: xxxxxxxxx.com Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: xxxxxxxxxxxx.com

SMTP server error: 5.7.1 : Client host rejected: Access denied
```

This is the code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
//$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$mail->Port = "587"; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "xxxxxxxxx";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("cpn@xichlomobile.com");
$mail->Subject = "Price Change Notification";
$mail->Body = "Test E-mail";
$mail->AddAddress("a.raja@xichlomobile.com");
 if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing which mail server you're running it's hard to be specific, but many people lock down their mail servers to only allow you to send mail from approved IP addresses.  This appears to be the case here.  You'll need to talk to the person who manages your mail server and get them to allow the web server to send mail.

Answer (score 1):

Try find if You are not in black list:

http://www.spamhaus.org/query/ip/10.0.0.10

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone dig in the issue above, please make sure that your username same as the `SetFrom` address. Some mail server configurations does not allow different sender addresses. The other option is simply add a mail aliase to the actual mail account.